# CSS selector :first-child appears to be ignored when applying styling to elements inside that selector

Tags: css, sass, css-selectors

I'm using SASS's `&`-nesting to apply a background to `:first-child` elements, but would also like to apply unique styling to certain other elements **within** those `:first-child` elements.

Here is the SASS:

```css
// Part Tree
.part-tree-item{
    ... 

    &:first-child{
        background: red;

        .part-tree-item-header{
            top: -5px;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

The CSS `:first-child` selector appears to work just fine, applying a red background to first children (and only first children):

[image]

However, as you can see from the SASS, I have some special styling I'd like to apply to only `.part-tree-item-header` elements within a `.part-tree-item:first-child`

Here, I'm showing the styling of the `.part-tree-item-header` within a `.part-tree-item` element that is **not** `:first-child` (note the lack of a red background, indicating as such).

However, this `.part-tree-item-header` still has the special case SASS (adjusting it's `top` and `margin-top` styling)

[image]

Here is the HTML, for proof that the `.part-tree-item` parent in question is not, in fact, a `:first-child`:

[image]

Am I just using the `:first-child` selector incorrectly? Does it not chain like I think it does? Can I only use it as the final part of a selector?

Any help would be vastly appreciated!!!

Comment: Instead of  `top: -5px`, have you tried `margin-top: -5px`?

Comment: The only explanation for this is that there is some distant .part-tree-item ancestor that *is* the first child of its parent.

Comment: Ahhhhh, thank you, BoltClock! This is actually only a small chunk of the tree. It's part of a larger, infinitely recursive tree. And all the inner cells (the red one and white one) are part of a `:first-child` element. Makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only explanation for this is that there is some distant `.part-tree-item` ancestor that is the first child of its parent.

To resolve this, add a child combinator to the `.part-tree-item-header` rule to ensure that the only `.part-tree-item:first-child` in relation to the `.part-tree-item-header` is its parent, not any of its ancestors that would otherwise match the selector:

```css
// Part Tree
.part-tree-item{
    ... 

    &:first-child{
        background: red;

        > .part-tree-item-header{
            top: -5px;
            margin-top: 0;
        }
    }
}
```